# Prove that K/L is a Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I need help in this proof.

The question is:
Let be F a field. Suppose that $car(F) \not=2$, which $car(F)$ means the characteric and let be $K/F$ an extension with $[K/F]=2$. Prove that $K/F$ is a Galois extension.

I have no idea how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Answer yourself this: if $\{1, \alpha\}$ is a basis of $K/F$ and $\alpha$ has minimal polynomial $f$ (which has degree $2$), then what do you need to show about $K, \alpha$ and $f$ to conclude that $K/F$ is a Galois extension?

Comment: Do I need to show that K is the splitting field of f?

Comment: Look at your notes. Does it say that a Galois extension is a splitting field of a polynomial, or is there a condition missing?

Comment: It is an equivalence. K is a Galois extension iff K is a splitting field of a separable polynomial f in F[x]

Comment: Right "separable". So you need to show that $f$ is separable and $K$ is the splitting field of $f$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll do it!

Answer (score 1):

Normal:

Let $a$ be an element of $K$ not in $F$, $1,a$ is a $F$-basis of $K$, you have $a^2=ua+v$, it implies that $a$ is a root of $P(X)=X^2-uX-v$ we deduce that $K$ is the splitting field of $P$. Divide $P$ by $X-a$, you have $P(X)=(X-a)(X-b)+c$, since $P(a)=0$, we deduce that $P(X)=(X-a)(X-b)$.

Separable:

if $a$ in $K$ not in $F$ the minimal polynomial $P=(X-a)(X-b)$ of $a$ has degree $2$, $P'=2X-a-b$ $P'(a)=0$ implies that $a-b=0$, we deduce that $a=b$, $P=(X-a)^2=X^2-2a+a^2$ since the characteristic is not $2$, $2a\neq 0$ and is an element of $F$, we deduce that $a\in F$ contradiction, so $P'(a)\neq 0$.